# How SSL communication between Azure AKS pods using Azure CNI can be enabled?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I have deployed an Azure AKS cluster using Azure CNI behind Application Gateway. Currently, internal pod communication is via http. I am trying to make this communication secure by implementing SSL. I didn't find any optimal solution after skimming through MSDN and Kubernetes documentation. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CNI won't automatically encrypt the communication between pods on its own.
You could use external tools like Linkerd or Istio which could encrypt traffic between pods

Linkerd and Isito will encrypt traffic with mTLS out of the box.

https://linkerd.io/2/features/automatic-mtls/

https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/tasks/security/authentication/auto-mtls/